# The very definition of an inner product

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality

Let's consider a finite, n-dimensional inner product space. My first question is, is the inner product between a pair of vectors $v_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ie_i$ and $v_2=\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_ie_i$ where $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a basis, only defined when $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is orthogonal?
In the case of $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ being orthonormal, then 
$$(a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^n \beta^*_i\alpha_i$$
But what if $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is not orthogonal? Will the inner product between $a$ and $b$ be still given by the same above formula?

Comment: It defines a different inner product.

Comment: you can define different inner products, namely $(u,v)=u X X^*v$ for any invertible matrix $X$. those inner products will define different norms $\|u\|^2 = (u,u)$ but will all are said "equivalent". now if you replace $XX^*$ by $M$ you get $(u,v) = u M v$, which is an inner product whenever $M$ is positive definite. and the spectral theorem (diagonalization) says that $M = P D P^*$. if $M$ is not of that form, $(u,v)$ won't respect the rules of the inner product anymore, and $\|u\| $ won't be a norm (you will have some $u$ with $\|u\| < 0$ ...) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Comment: If I can define a different inner products, does this mean that an inner product is not basis-independent?

Comment: Ah I get it now, after reading up again my textbook, an inner product is any mathematical operation defined to have the following properties: positivity, definiteness, linearity in the first argument, homogeneity in the first argument, and conjugate symmetry. It doesn't necessarily take the form I assumed to be true in all cases above.

Answer (score 2):

Before you have an inner product, you can't say that the standard one is orthogonal. Orthogonality acquired meaning in the presence of an inner product. You can define different inner products, and for each you will get different collections of orthogonal, or orthonormal, bases. Fixing an inner product, say on a real vector space, you then can easily show that for each orthonormal basis the inner product $\langle u, v\rangle$ is represented as $\sum u_kv_k$, where the $u_k,v_k$ are the coefficients of $u,v$, respectively, in the chosen orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0):

Your last comment shows you are becoming more proficient with the concept of an inner product.

Yes, the inner product can exist in many different forms -- e.g., in the form of an integral for polynomial function spaces.  The *dot product* that you learn in Calc III is another specific example of an inner product.

You must be in an inner-product space *first* before talking about orthogonality.

Finally, inner products induce norms on vector spaces.  You should check what this means.